# Creating a thumbnail in a S3 bucket with a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was studying Lambda for the first time and I was using the AWS Lambda tutorial: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

It does not even work for me for a file size of 60Kb. This is as far as I have made it:

- Created the 2 buckets, uploaded the source file in the source bucket (67KB), named it `HappyFace.jpg`.
- Created the Lambda role
- I was able to create the Lambda function running the CLI command
- I was able to create the `output.txt`, BUT in this step, the output.txt file gets created but it is void (0 KB), also the manual invoke does not create the thumbnail in my destination bucket.

Since the manual invoke test does not work, whenever I upload a new image in my src bucket, nothing happens again.

I am using a cygwin Linux emulator in my windows 10 laptop, using the latest node.js version 12.x and using CLI ver1.x (tried to upgrade it to ver 2.x but was not successful, I am a Linux newbie).

I just passed the AWS Architect Associate exam and I have the AWS fever hehe, I just can't get this bug out of my head, I want to make this work. I suspect that there must be an issue with my `index.js` file

Can you help?

Comment: What are the logs for the Lambda function execution in CloudWatch logs? Are there any errors there?

Comment: Greetings Tamas, thanks so much for responding!

I recreated the scenario again last night, this time I did as the document says, on the us-west-2 region, I created 2 buckets, one "source-bucket" and the other "source-bucket-resized".  this is what I see in the logs:

2020-09-28T23:50:15.228Z undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception {"errorType":"Runtime.HandlerNotFound","errorMessage":"index.handler is undefined or not exported","stack":

Comment: whenever I manually invoke the Lambda function, the output file gets created but there it has a size of 0Bytes, basically creates a void file and the pic that lies on the source bucket is not resized and added to the source bucket "-resized"

Comment: the function gets created, I can see it in my console, but the manual invoke does not do a thing. this is what the prompt shows:

~/lambda-s3
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name CreateThumbnail --invocation-type Event \
> --payload file://inputFile.txt outputfile.txt
{
    "StatusCode": 202
}

Comment: The index.handler not found error is the key here. It seems like Lambda can not find your function. index.handler means it looks the index.js file and tries to find the exported "handler". In the example project it looks like this: exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {...} . Do you have this in your index.js and are the names match?